# Powershell script send test print with part of the printers name

Tags: powershell

Task: Send a test print to a printer with partial naming. This script will run on multiple machines to send test prints to the printer. All the printers names are similar but with an added floor and dept example (Accounting LL M402dn 01, Security 1st-M402dn-02, and etc.

Problem: I realized that all the printer names share the model of the printer so I was I thinking of using that to be able to find the printers. However its having a problem picking up the model number with a wildcard

```
$printerName = "M402dn" 
Get-CimInstance Win32_Printer -Filter "name LIKE '*$printerName*'" |
            Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName printtestpage
```

What am i doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try replacing `*` with `%` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/like-operator).

Comment: nice thanks that worked! so that was what I was missing. The link is very useful too

Comment: Why not just provide a list to pick from then pass that to your method?    [$printerName = Get-CimInstance Win32_Printer | Out-GridView -Title 'Select a printer so send a test page to' -OutputMode Single]   This would avoid any human fat-fingering stuff. You, of course, would not have to use OGV, as you could pass this list a validation/intelliSense  to the user.